# Configuring multiple SOAP services in Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, soap

My application needs to consume several SOAP services that I have no ability to modify (they were imported into Visual Studio and the classes were automatically generated). I've wrapped each service in my own custom class (so that I can extend functionality), and each of those wrappers lives in its own Class Library project. My main application then instantiates my wrappers to use the services. Like this:

```
MyProject.Service1 (class library)
    - instantiates and uses RemoteService1
    - has app.config file

MyProject.Service2 (class library)
    - instantiates and uses RemoteService2
    - has app.config file

MyProject (web application)
    - instantiates and uses MyProject.Service1 and MyProject.Service2
    - has Web.config file
```

When Visual Studio auto-generated the classes for the remote services, the app.config file was updated. Here's the one for `MyProject.Service1`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="RemoteService1HttpBinding">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint
                address="http://path.com/to/RemoveService1"
                binding="customBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="RemoteService1HttpBinding"
                contract="RemoteService1Contract" 
                name="RemoteService1Name" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I then manually copy-pasted the binding and client information into the `MyProject` Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="RemoteService1HttpBinding">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>
       </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint
            address="http://path.com/to/RemoveService1"
            binding="customBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="RemoteService1HttpBinding"
            contract="RemoteService1Contract" 
            name="RemoteService1Name" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

That works just fine. I'm able to instantiate a new `MyService.Service1` object and make calls to the `RemoteService1` SOAP service.

The problem is that I haven't been able to configure the second service. I tried to manually add the auto-generated app.config settings to the Web.config file, but I got this error:

`The element <customBinding> may only appear once in this section.`

How am I supposed to configure multiple SOAP services?

Comment: Ah, you're right! That worked great. Same with `<client />` having multiple endpoints. If you copy your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many bindings as you want within your binding section so long as you give each a distinct name. On your endpoint, you specify the type and name of the binding which you would like to use. The `binding` property refers to the type of binding, and the `bindingConfiguration` refers to the name of the binding of that type which you want to use.